# scikit-learn: plot_roc_curve with pipeline as estimator

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, roc

Is there any way to use plot_roc_curve with a pipeline as the estimator? I mean:

```
plot_roc_curve(pipeline, X_test, y_test)
```

Comment: What version/s?

Answer (score 0):

With scikit-learn 0.22, it works like a charm.

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import plot_roc_curve

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)
pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogisticRegression())
pipe.fit(X, y)
plot_roc_curve(pipe, X, y)
```